CSS Selector if parent has class
Now that there is CSS Nesting, if I'm using a body-level class for "dark" or "light" mode, I would love to set attributes to a selector that's deep in the nest by referencing the parent:
body{
  .header{
    .button{
      .image{
        background-color: white;
      .image::has-parent(.dark-mode){ <-- something like this
        background-color: black;
...

I assume this violates some core CSS principles, but I figured I'd ask just in case! Is there an alternative technique for this?
This is different (as I understand it) from the :has selector because :has means has child or sibling. There is not a selector that selects if it has a parent.
Here's an example snippet:


div{
 &.dark{
   background-color:black;
 }
 .child{
   /* doesn't work */
   &:has(.dark){
     color:white;
   }
 }
<div>
 <div class="child">Should be dark text on white background</div>
</div>

<div class="dark">
 <div class="child">Should be white text on dark background</div>
</div>




No, that's quite simple. Add some appropriate html to your question and we'll show you how.

I added a snippet

It seems you are over-complicating this. What you want is the selector .dark .child that you can write like below


div{
 &.dark{
   background-color:black;
 }
 .child{
   .dark &{
     color:white;
   }
 }
<div>
 <div class="child">Should be dark text on white background</div>
</div>

<div class="dark">
 <div class="child">Should be white text on dark background</div>
</div>




There are ways to do this, but they all lead to nesting hell and trying to override things.
I'd suggest using CSS variables instead, where you can define a set of them to control your themed color schemes. For example:
body.light-mode {
  --theme-text-color: black;
  --theme-background-color: white;
}
body.dark-mode {
  --theme-text-color: white;
  --theme-background-color: black;
}

and then for your image CSS, you can just reference:
.image {
  background-color: var(--theme-background-color);
}

This will allow you to keep your theme-based settings easily organized in one place, and then just reference them throughout the rest of your codebase. This is also helpful for example, if you wanted to change your darkmode background from black to #222222 without needing to make that update for every element that references it

For this particular example, sure - but it isn't always something so generalizable as a theme color. For example, a button that uses a different background image based on dark mode or light mode. Of course, using custom css properties is a great approach if possible and un-nesting is likely the solution for most cases ~ but I do wonder if there's a way to keep the nesting...

If you're using SASS already, you can do it to a degree with .dark-mode & { ... } to apply rules to the item you're currently working on if it has .dark-mode as a parent class somewhere up the chain. This does some strange things with inheritance though if you're not careful, so you need to look at what it's generating

You could also look into another pre-processor or writing something that will re-organize your CSS using a fully custom syntax. In this case, if it is a fully different theme, the most efficient end result would be to do something like that and have it generate two different stylesheets as its end result. Then when the theme changes, you just swap out the whole thing and prevent a user from loading in more CSS rules than necessary upfront

@BobtheMagicMoose if you're interested in that approach, here's a JSFiddle of a way of doing it via JS. If you use something like Gulp you can add a function like this into your pipeline to split out your SCSS output before compiling it into the two separate versions https://jsfiddle.net/d0s2a1kb/

I'm not using a preprocessor. My main inquiry was whether there were a way to have my cake and eat it too: have the structure of my CSS file roughly match the HTML tree AND condition some styles of child elements based on parent/root classes. It looks like that isn't possible.

@BobtheMagicMoose ah I saw the ampersands in your example snippet and assumed it was using SASS or LESS. And at the very least you should be using a minifier of some kind, there isn't a scenario where you should just be writing CSS and deploying as-is
